# Lambda defined in AWS IoT rule is not triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-core, aws-iot-events

I setup a fleet-provisioning and it's working perfectly.
I'm listening on the topic `$aws/provisioning-templates/{}/provision/json/accepted` and I'm getting response
`{"deviceConfiguration":{},"thingName":"1234567-abcde-fghij-klmno-1234567abc-TLS350"}`

When I'm trying to listen on the same topic inside AWS IOT MQTT client I'm getting `Incorrect topic format. This topic is not supported`.

My final idea is to make AWS IoT rule which is going to listen on this topic and trigger lambda but currently doesn't work with the following statement:
`SELECT * from '$aws/provisioning-templates/fleet-provisioning-template/provision/json/accepted'`. Do you have idea what is going on here?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have required invoke permissions for your lambda to get triggered?

Comment: Yes, I have required invoke permission. Permission from terraform script looks like this: `resource "aws_lambda_permission" "this" {
  statement_id  = "iot-events"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.this.function_name
  principal     = "iot.amazonaws.com"
}`. What is more I've tested rule with this lambda with different topic and its working.

Comment: check this question's answers on stackoverflow. It might help you: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907529/google-cloud-iot-invalid-mqtt-publish-topic)